# How do I prevent users from accessing my application at an incorrect time and date?

Tags: java, android, firebase, datetime

I want to create a system that prevents the user from entering the app if the date and time are not configured properly on the user's device.

same as WhatsApp lock:

[image: Thumbnail of YouTube video]

Can this be done with a Firebase date and time as a reference?

Does anyone have any idea how this lockout is done?

Here's what I've done so far:

```java
Calendar calFordDate = Calendar.getInstance();
SimpleDateFormat currentDate = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMMM-yyyy");
saveCurrentDate = currentDate.format(calFordDate.getTime());

Calendar calFordTime = Calendar.getInstance();
SimpleDateFormat currentTime = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
saveCurrentTime = currentTime.format(calFordTime.getTime());
PostRandomName = saveCurrentDate + saveCurrentTime;
```

Comment: You will need to use security rules on the backend, as the client device may choose its own time in order to fool whatever code checks the date and time in the app.

Comment: Get the correct time from somewhere on the Internet, be it your own server or somewhere else. Search for how, this has been asked and answered a number of times. Compare with the device time as you get it from for example `Instant.now()` or `System.currentTimeMillis()` (the two mentioned options are independent of time zone). Allow a margin.

Answer (score 0):

Get `DateTime` through `API` is the way to prevent user with changed phone date time from accessing your app

Time zone must be put in consideration